# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

I'm using MVC3 and SQL 2005.  I was getting error: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." I believe this was being generated because I was using "1" instead of "1.00000" for QTYORDER.  Using "1.00000" for QTYORDER I now see the error: "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."

I've tried using Convert.ToInt32(Variable) like below:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTYSOLD", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(QTYORDER);`

Which returns: "Input string was not in a correct format."  Int.Parse(QTYORDER) does the same thing...

The SQL Stored Proc Variables:

```
Procedure [dbo].[SVC_AddPart_To_Service_Call]      
    (@SRVRECTYPE smallint,
     @CALLNBR char(11),
     @TECHID char(11),
     @LINITMTYP char(3),
     @ITEMNMBR char(31),
     @QTY numeric(19,5) = 0,
     @QTYSOLD numeric(19,5) = 0,
     @STARTDATE datetime = '01/01/1900 00:00:00',   
     @STARTTIME datetime = '01/01/1900 00:00:00',
     @ENDDATE datetime = '01/01/1900 00:00:00',
     @ENDTIME datetime = '01/01/1900 00:00:00',
     @Status int output) As ...
```

The MVC C# Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CPLU"].ConnectionString);
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SVC_AddPart_To_Service_Call", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SRVRECTYPE", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = "2";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CALLNBR", SqlDbType.Char).Value = CALLNBR;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TECHID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Session["TechID"];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LINITMTYP", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "P";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITEMNMBR", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ITEMNMBR;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QTYORDER;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTYSOLD", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QTYORDER;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@STARTDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@STARTTIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENDDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENDTIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@STATUS", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@STATUS"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

The MVC Razor Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CALLNBR, "Call Number")
            @Html.Label("CALLNBR", (string)ViewBag.CALLNBR)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMDESC)
        <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEMNMBR, "Item Number")
            @Html.DropDownList("ITEMNMBR", (SelectList) ViewBag.Items, "Please Select a Part #")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMNMBR)
        <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEMDESC, "Description")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ITEMDESC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMDESC)
        <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QTYORDER, "Quantity")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QTYORDER, new { required = "required"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QTYORDER)
        <br />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Add Part" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

Values I'm trying to pass through the form:

```
CALLNBR = 0000198210 
ITEMNMBR = RF5-1885 (22 trailing spaces)
QTYORDER = 1
```

Values taken from a line in the SQL Table:

```
CALLNBR = 0000198638  
ITEMNMBR = RM1-0043 (22 trailing spaces)
QTYORDER = 1.00000
```

Questions:

1) Since the SP has default values coded for STARTDATE, STARTTIME, ENDDATE, and ENDTIME... do I need to supply those values when adding the parameters on the MVC App?

2) How would I go about using a Try-Catch here and would that give me a better error message?  Something I could actually follow up on?

3) Is there a way to cast the QTYORDER value to 5 decimal places in C#?  This would make sure it submits in the #.00000 format...

Considerations:

I'm using Entity Framework, but I can't map the Stored Proc to the Select Insert Function for that table because that SP is used for adding a part, and another SP is used for adding labor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer a couple of your questions, you do not need to pass optional parameters to a stored procedure -- they will use their default values.

In regards to try-catches, just do a quick search online and use your breakpoints -- I would put it around the entire block of code you provided above.  Should be able to get a better idea of the exception being thrown.

A few additional comments to consider:

Instead of trying int.parse, use int.TryParse:

```
int orderQty = 0;
int.TryParse(QTYORDER, out orderQty);
if (orderQty == 0)
    //You potentially have a problem with binding
```

Also, your code is passing QTYORDER as an integer, but the stored procedure is accepting a decimal.  Change this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QTYORDER;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTY", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = QTYORDER;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Haven't had a chance to put this hat back on in some time.  Changed sqldbtype from int to decimal for QTYORDER.  Now I get a NEW conversion error... yay!  "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: What line is that coming from?  What value is QTYORDER?  Use Decimal.TryParse instead of int.TryParse to convert it.  Good luck.

Comment: Looks like I needed sql type (int) for callnbr and techid, sql type (char) for linitmtyp and itemnmbr, and sql type (decimal) for qty and qtysold.  Now I'm getting yet another error... "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ITEMNMBR'."  As this error doesn't appear to be a conversion issue, I'm going to close this question, I'll create a new one after I've tried to run down this error myself.

Comment: You helped a ton.  I needed decimal... after that it was just figuring out the OTHER ones I needed... the more errors that are resolved, the more I seem to generate...  Oh well, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure QTYORDER is not null? MVC may have lost the model binding here. Do a quick check to see if its null

put this before you add params and add a breakpoint on the bool x line to see if it hits. If it is null then there is something wrong with the model binding, check your model code

```
if(QTYORDER == null){

     bool x = true;

}
```

Try trimming the string to ensure there is no spaces?

```
Convert.ToInt32(QTYORDER.Trim());
```

If you want to convert this to 5 decimal places

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(QTYORDER.Trim()), 5);
```